# Transformation of a differential equation into variables u &x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Suppose we have $Mdx+ Ndy=0$ We want to transform it into variable u&x such that $x=uy$

My attempt is below!

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=g(1/u)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{u-x\frac{du}{dx}}{u^2}$$

After getting the new separable differential equation use it to solve

$$(x^2-3y^2)dx+2xydy=0$$

Comment: $M$ and $N$ are functions of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes respectively, it is very messy

Comment: Can you help me I am entirely stuck at differential equation for this part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So given $\bbox[lemonchiffon,0.25ex]{x=uy}$ , then $\bbox[lemonchiffon,0.25ex]{\mathrm dx=y\,\mathrm du + u\,\mathrm dy}$, by the product rule.   Rearranging:

$$\mathrm d y = u^{-1}\,\mathrm d x-u^{-1}y\,\mathrm d u$$

Tip: $y$ terms are undesirable, so we substitute: $y\gets u^{-1}x$.

$$\mathrm d y = u^{-1}\,\mathrm d x-u^{-2}x\,\mathrm d u$$

Then using this to substitute into $\bbox[lemonchiffon,0.25ex]{N\mathrm d x+M\mathrm d y=0}$ we find...

Comment: For the last part I don't get it! $Ndx_Mdy=0$

Comment: Just substitute to get $N\mathrm d x + M (u^{-1}\mathrm d x-u^{-2}x\mathrm d u)=0$.

Comment: $\int_{} \frac{du}{u-u^2g(\frac{1}{u})}=\int_{}\frac{dx}{x}$

Comment: Thanks man! I was trapped in my mind and just found out the exact solution. You are a great help! Thank you for your time and effort.